# Pass code to a method as an argument

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, delegates, action

I have a list of methods that do pretty much the same thing, except a few differences:

```
void DoWork(string parameter1, string parameter2)

{

//Common code
...

//Custom code
...

//Common code
...

}
```

I want to streamline the solution with reusing the common code by passing custom code from another method.

I assume I have to use an action with parameters to accomplish this, but can't figure out how.

Comment: You are going to have to give a more complete example than that to get any help.

Comment: To be honest it's hard to give an accurate response when you have not provided enough information, **we are just trying to guess what might be the right answer for you based on assumptions** if you could provide more context would be great =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are great, but you may need to return something from the custom code, so you would need to use Func instead.

```
void Something(int p1, int p2, Func<string, int> fn)
{
   var num = p1 + p2 + fn("whatever");
   // . . .
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Something(1,2, x => { ...; return 1; });
```

Or:

```
int MyFunc(string x)
{
    return 1;
}

Something(1,2 MyFunc);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [**Template method pattern**](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx)

Which basically states soemthing like this

```
abstract class Parent
{
   public virtual void DoWork(...common arguments...)
   {
      // ...common flow
      this.CustomWork();
      // ...more common flow
   }

   // the Customwork method must be overridden
   protected abstract void CustomWork();
}
```

In a child class

```
class Child : Parent
{
   protected override void CustomWork()
   {
      // do you specialized work
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to handle this.  It would likely look something like:

```
void DoWork(string parameter1, string parameter2, Action<string,string> customCode)
{
    // ... Common code
    customCode(parameter1, parameter2);
    // ... Common code
    customCode(parameter1, parameter2);
    // ... Common code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the custom code doesn't have to interact with the common code, it's easy:

```
void DoWork(..., Action custom)
{
    ... Common Code ...
    custom();
    ... Common Code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to use the two string parameters in the custom code, the following should get the job done.  If you don't actually care about the results of the custom code, you can replace `Func<string, string, TResult>` with `Action<string, string>`.  Additionally, if your custom code needs to process results from the common code above it, you can adjust the parameter types that your Func<> (or Action<>) takes in and then pass in the appropriate values.

```
void DoWork(string parameter1, string parameter2, Func<string, string, TResult> customCode) {
    //Common code 
    var customResult = customCode(parameter1, parameter2);
    //Common code 
}
```

Using `Func<T, TResult>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960

Using `Action<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8