# How to pass code blocks (not full methods) as arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, delegates

I'm building a messaging app in csharp (.net 4.0), my class has basic methods for sending/receiving messages:

```
void sendMessage( string msgBody, string properties);
object getNextMessage();
object getMessageById( string msgId);
```

Each of these methods depends on an underlying connection; if the connection is stale, I use try/catch and some retry logic to make additional attempts, something like this:

```
public object getNextMessage(){
   object nextMessage = null;
   int retryAttempts = 0;
   int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;

   while( retryAttempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS){
      retryAttempts++;
      try{
         nextMessage = connection.getMessage("queueName");
      }catch(Exception e){   
      }
   }
   return nextMessage;
}
```

Since the retry logic is generic, I want to avoid repeating the same code in each method. I want to create a common retry function and do something like this:

```
public object makeAttempt( CodeBlock codeBlock){
       while( retryAttempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS){
          retryAttempts++;
          try{
             return codeBlock.invoke()
          }catch(Exception e){   
          }
       }
       return null;
}
```

..I want to use `makeAttempt` like this, or something similar:

```
public object getNextMessage(){       
   makeAttempt() => {
      return connection.getMessage("queueName");
   }
}
```

I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10903874/791406), but it relates to passing entire functions as arguments, which I'm not doing. I also reviewed [.net Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), but I'm not seeing a connection.

I haven't done much C# so forgive the n00b question :-)

Comment: You have already looked up exactly the tools that you need to solve this problem.  A lambda is nothing more than a terse syntax for creating a new method, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: a codeblock, or an anonymous function (lambda) is exactly what you need. that;s how you pass codeblocks around

Comment: @Servy: Not *literally* already done - the code in `makeAttempt` and `getNextMessage` won't compile yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, I meant that he already has the answer to his question.  Poor phrasing.

Comment: That's pseudocode, I should have mentioned earlier.

Comment: @raffian: Yes, you should have done - given that I assume you want *actual* code in an answer, and your "pseudocode" is almost exactly what you need.

Comment: Side note; rather than ignoring all exceptions resulting from the retries, consider holding onto them and re-throwing them in an `AggregateException` in the event all of the retires fail, rather than returning null.  Both because `null` could be a valid result of the function call, and because the callers then have meaningful information about why it failed.

Comment: Interesting, was not aware of `AggregateException`, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @raffian If a system version didn't exist, it would be trivial enough to create one of your own.  It's just an exception that has a collection of exceptions inside of it.

Comment: I know, the original code was psuedo, I left out details for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're nearly there at the end - you just need to enclose the lambda expression in `()` as it's a method argument. You also need to use the return value from `makeAttempt` to provide a return value for your `getNextMessage` method. So:

```
public object getNextMessage(){       
   return makeAttempt(() => {
      return connection.getMessage("queueName");
   });
}
```

Or more simply, use an expression lambda:

```
public object getNextMessage(){       
   return makeAttempt(() => connection.getMessage("queueName"));
}
```

This is all assuming that `CodeBlock` is a delegate type, of course, e.g.

```
public delegate object CodeBlock();
```

You also need to change `makeAttempt` to call `Invoke` rather than `invoke` - C# is case-sensitive. I'd strongly urge you to follow .NET naming conventions, too, where methods are `PascalCased` instead of `camelCased`.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you could make this generic:

```
public T CallWithRetries<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= MaxAttempts; attempt++)
    {
        try
        {
            return function();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: Logging
        }
    }
    // TODO: Consider throwing AggregateException here
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: @Servy: Well it's close enough to real code that it's worth correcting to *be* real code.

Comment: Ahh, very nice, so I was pretty close! Can I use the same `makeAttempt()` for code blocks that don't return anything? Or do I have to create two versions of `makeAttempt()`?

Comment: @raffian The best option is to make two versions; anything else would be a hack, generally involving returning a value you don't care about.

Comment: That's what I was thinking; confirmation is much appreciated.

Comment: @JonSkeet Does `CodeBlock` have to do anything other than being declared a delegate type? I'm curious why it's even necessary; is there no generic delegate I can use?

Comment: @raffian Yes there is, you can use `Action` for the procedural code block and `Func<T>` for the functional one that returns a result.

Comment: @raffian: Yes, you could use `Func<object>` instead - or make it generic. I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: Had to make a quick edit to your last example, can you confirm? everything else is working sweet!

Comment: Thx for this answer bro! I actually was able to make what i wanted to :D